# Windows 10 I/O causes audio hiccups

Tags: windows-10, priority

Basically, when heavy I/O is happening it causes audio to break up and it's really annoying during conference calls. Even just loading a more demanding webpage is enough to do this, the other day I ran git reflog and that broke my voice according to colleagues. Is there a way to tune the Windows 10 scheduler to give more priority to certain browser tabs or something?

Comment: Most browsers reduce the priority or refresh rates of tabs when they are not focused, are you able to use a dedicated application from your call provider to deal with these issues?

Comment: I've observed similar symptoms on a few computers. In each case the system was plenty capable, but bad drivers or audio assistance apps caused the problems. Have you checked for and installed the latest drivers and firmware?

Comment: @Mokubai I am unaware of a Google Meet app for Windows. The one on the phone is waaaay too loud and as such, unusable. I will try to find a better sound mixer for Android but still, I'd like to use my laptop for Google Meet...